# Can I load case_id into a registration form?

Tags: commcare

Can I reference the case_id of the case I'm trying to create in a registration form? When I use *instance('commcaresession')/session/data/case_id* in my registration form I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, HQ injects all of the Case XML code into the form later, so there's no "clean" way of referencing what will become the caseID most of the time